# How to launch a gmail client with a specific email

Tags: browser, gmail, imap, launch

I have a browser application that retrieves gmail items in inbox using IMAP. I have the 'seqno' and the Message-ID of the email, and can fetch the content. I've created and rendered HTML with that email as a link. What I would like to do is to launch another browser with that email displayed in gmail client.

I noticed that there is no correlation between Gmail's URLs and the Message-ID or 'seqno'. How do I translate my ID into a URL that would launch the right email?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can.  However check [Gmail's IMAP Extensions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions), specifically, see if X-GM-MSGID correlates at all with the URLs.